# Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, html

Debo guardar los `id` de los roles que se guarden, pero estoy teniendo este error:

```
trim() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

Estos `id` se seleccionan de un `multiselect` y recojo los datos en el `select` y los convierto a `string` para guardarlos, así:

```
$tipo = isset($_POST["txttipo"]);
count(array($tipo));
json_encode($tipo);
```

Y el `select` es este:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="Seleccionar" name="txttipo[]" id="txttipo"></select>
```

Comment: Dices que tu error es *trim() expects parameter 1 to be string* pero en el código que has puesto no veo ni un solo uso de `trim()`... por favor, pon el código relacionado con el error para que podamos ayudarte. Recuerda que la mejor manera de explicar un error es proporcionar un [mre].

Comment: @Benito-B No estoy haciendo uso de  `trim()`, eso es lo curioso, ese código es lo único que estoy usando

Comment: Por qué almacenas en tipo isset? Supongo que sabés qué lo que se almacena es un booleano. Qué raro qué no teniendo un trim() en tu código te de ese error.

Comment: ¿No sería `count($tipo)` en vez de `count(array($tipo))`? Además estás enviando un array y tendrás que recorrerlo antes de hacer un `trim`. Otra observación es que `isset` te da un `boolean` y tendrás que poner `$_POST["txttipo"]` y no `isset($_POST["txttipo"])`, haciendo un `isset()` te dará un `boolean`, por lo que `count` no funcionará y `trim()` dará este error debido a que estás tratando de enviar un `boolean` como `string`

Comment: Puedes quitar esta línea: `count(array($tipo));`, no le veo la función y te esta causando el error.

Comment: Al quitar la línea  `count(array($tipo));` recibo el mismo error, no cambia

Comment: @PHJ La solución es muy fácil, cambia `isset($_POST["txttipo"])` por `$_POST["txttipo"]`

Comment: @anythingg Al eliminar el `isset` recibo el error: `Undefined index: txttipo` el nombre del select, cuando el name sigue siendo el mismo, pero pasa al quitar el isset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando un `isset` antes de tiempo, como te dije en los comentarios, estás obteniendo un `boolean` con `isset`, y `trim()` no funcionará  ya que estás enviando un `bool` y `trim()` requiere de un `string`

```php
if (isset($_POST["txttipo"])) {
    print json_encode($_POST["txttipo"]);
}
```

Además, estás haciendo un `count(array)`

Esto no es correcto, `array` es una palabra reservada para definir arrays, la forma correcta es `count($_POST["txttipo"])`

No entiendo lo necesario en esa línea, ya que no utilizas nunca ese dato.

---

Si quieres almacenar tu "if dentro de una variable" puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$valid = isset($_POST["txttipo"]);
if ($valid) {
    print json_encode($_POST["txttipo"]);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero una pregunta, con respecto al código PHP no podría almacenar el `if` dentro de una variable, para después hacer ciertas validaciones?

Comment: Claro que puedes, déjame editarlo

Comment: Si, siento los errores, estoy iniciando :)

Comment: @JuanRivera no me di cuenta de que el OP estaba usando un select múltiple, el `[]` es para múltiples, lo deje porque puede ser de utilidad

Comment: @anythingg Entonces siempre podría hacer uso de `count($_POST["txttipo"])` haciendo referencia a que como es un múltiple select, recorrer los valores que se seleccionan?

Comment: @PHJ El método `count` te da el número de elementos contenidos en un array, para recorrer las opciones seleccionadas puedes usar `foreach`, puedes leer más acerca de foreach en el [manual de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @anythingg en mi opinion lo sigo viendo el select como algo innecesario pero te doy un +1 por la explicacion dada, aunque aun tengo la duda, porque le salia error de trim?

Comment: @JuanRivera No hay ningún trim y puede que el OP lo haya quitado antes de publicar su pregunta